# callAsync AndroidStudio XMLRPC

Tags: android, android-studio, callback

Estoy realizando una conexión asíncrona en una app de android, pero a la hora de poner las credenciales y logear se me cierra la app. Sin embargo si hago una conexión síncrona funciona perfecto.

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4148
              Process: com.example.pargibay.androidphprpcxml, PID: 20553
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:209)
                  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:123)
                  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:349)
                  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:105)
                  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:263)
                  at com.example.pargibay.androidphprpcxml.MainActivity$3.onResponse(MainActivity.java:112)
                  at de.timroes.axmlrpc.XMLRPCClient$Caller.run(XMLRPCClient.java:588)
```

Llamada Asíncrona (no funciona) ->

```
client.callAsync(listener,"examples.login", new Object[]{users,
passw});
```

Comment: Recuerda poner parte de tú codigo o tú codigo para que quienes veamos tu pregunta podamos ayudarte.
Pero debes revisar el MainActivity.

Comment: Bueno ya logré hace unas semanas que se conecte vía síncrona y asíncrona. Como no había mucha documentación decidí hacer yo una para los nuevos en este tema. https://github.com/pargibaycalvo/XMLRPC-Android-Synchronous-Asynchronous